# Python paramenter js=True

Tags: python

I'm quite new to Python and I cannot find any docs explaining what the parameter **js=True** means in the Requests library function:

```
def somename (url, payload=None,js=True)
    if payload == None:
        request = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    else:
        request = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
    if js == True:
        request= request.json()
return request
```

Could someone help, please?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with requests. It's just a default value for a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielRoseman, but do you know the meaning of js, please?

Comment: What meaning? It's just the name of a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielRoseman!

Comment: That parameter is used in this conditional statement .. `if js == True:`. `someone` isn't part of the requests package.

Comment: its a default parameter so the variable is not empty at any time in case you don't send that parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that a default value will be held in case you do not fill that parameter on function. Because it might be required internally for something and needs a default value to be set event if is intentionally left blank. In case you need more enlightenment follow this URL: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-arguments-in-python/

```
def a(check=True):
    return check
```

Example:

```
a(check=True) # True
a(check=False) # False
a() # True
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation and for the link. Really appreciate!